# Pass additional arguments into javascript event

Tags: javascript, jquery, function-pointers

I'm trying to use a JavaScript function with as an event handler for jQuery, but it needs one additional peice of information.  I tried adding it on to an object with the data, and using `this`, but `this` is null when it gets executed.  I believe this has something to do with function copying with in JavaScript.  How can I pass my extra info.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var WIDTH_ATTR = 'initWidth';

function resizeHandler(event, ui){
    var change = ui.size.width - this.master.attr(WIDTH_ATTR);
    this.slave.width(slave.attr(WIDTH_ATTR) - change);
};

function splitResize(master, slave, masterHandles){
    var s = new SharedResize(master, slave);
    master.resizable({ handles: masterHandles, resize: s.resizeHandler }); 
}

function SharedResize(master, slave){
    this.master = master;
    this.slave = slave;
    this.resizeHandler = resizeHandler;
    master.attr(WIDTH_ATTR, master.width());
    slave.attr(WIDTH_ATTR, slave.width());
}

// initialise plugins
$(function(){
    try {
        $('ul.sf-menu').superfish();
        splitResize($('#Content'), $('#InfoPanel'));
    }catch(ex){
        alert(ex.message);
    }
});
</script>
```

This code gives an error of

```
Line:13
'this.master' is null or not an object.
```

When a resize is attempted.

Can I make this scheme work, or is there another way to associate the event handler with my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this change:

```
function splitResize(master, slave, masterHandles){
    var s = new SharedResize(master, slave);
    master.resizable({ handles: masterHandles, 
        resize: function(event, ui) { s.resizeHandler(event, ui); } }); 
}
```

With that, the "resize" handler will be an anonymous function that, in turn, calls your handler with the proper context (the "SharedResize" instance).

Comment: thanks that works!  I had to tweak your closure, but it got me close enough.  I updated your answer to reflect my changes.

Comment: Oh ok good - I wasn't sure exactly what you meant by the "extra parameters" thing :-)

Comment: my original goal was to just pass in `master` and `slave` to the resize handler directly.  I see how I could do that now, using a closure, but the object version is already written.

Answer (score 1):

You can either do what Pointy suggested or you can do this:

```
function SharedResize(master, slave){
    this.master = master;
    this.slave = slave;
    this.resizeHandler = function(event, ui){
       var change = ui.size.width - this.master.attr(WIDTH_ATTR);
       this.slave.width(slave.attr(WIDTH_ATTR) - change);
    };
    master.attr(WIDTH_ATTR, master.width());
    slave.attr(WIDTH_ATTR, slave.width());
}
```